# Selenium can not click on GWT tree item

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gwt

I can't give access to the webapp but here is the code and HTML of the button

```
 we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"));
 int width = we.getSize().getWidth();
 action.moveToElement(we, width/2, 9).click().build().perform();
```

.

```
<div style="display: inline; background-color: rgb(255, 179, 0);" class="gwt-TreeItem gwt-TreeItem-selected" role="treeitem" id="gwt-uid-102" aria-level="9" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="1" aria-selected="true">
```

Comment: For those coming to this post to provide an answer, I switched to using the c# web backed driver. I have something against answering my own question but if that's the most appropriate way to mark this question as answered, then I will.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']

the above is how we should write the XPath in a code you did just give a tag name but no attribute so try to change how you give XPath

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"));
action.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: The problem with that method is that the IDs are generated differently every time. The object is being found correctly. If I have a contextClick, that will show up at the appropriate spot

Comment: You can try class attribute too instead of ID

Comment: As I already mentioned, the issue isn't with the finding of the element. it's an issue of clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

May be the element is not clickable when you are trying to click it. You can wait for element to become clickable and then try clicking it, as shown below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")).click();
```

If above code does not work for you, then you can use Javascriptexecutor as a workaround, as shown below:

```
JavascriptExecutor e = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
e.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")));
```

Let me know, whether above solution works for you.

Comment: I switched to the c# web backed driver

Answer (score 0):

When you run selenium TCs, make sure that the browser maximized. Sometimes, it may happen that elements overlap due to smaller resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I switched to the c# web backed driver because it uses the clickat command.